# retrieving data with a checkbox - angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Suppose I have some model instances, (that I don't call from an angularJS file but from my `rails` controller)

```
 = f.fields_for :models, model do |builder|
          %ul
            = builder.hidden_field :some_id
            = check_box_tag :id => "some_value"
```

I want to add `some_value` as a value to the `hidden_field` as soon as the checkbox is checked. How can I do that with `angularJS` ?

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're generating AngularJS HTML files as rails views you are somehow defying one of the purposes of AngularJS: being a client side templating system, based on static files.

(see these slides to get an idea: http://www.slideshare.net/JamieDavidson2/rails-angular-meetup)

regarding your question, you have to setup an Angular controller to define a scope, then link the value of the `check_box_tag` to the scope using `ng-model` and that of the `hidden_field` to the same model but through a function that gives the right string based on the checkbox state.

If you want to keep it simple, for this use case you'd better use JQuery